# How do I find the font style in a documentclass?

Tags: fonts

Specifically, I want to generate figures that have captions with the same font as in svmono.cls.  However, more generally, is there a simple way to identify what font style a documentclass uses?

Comment: As far as I can see `svmono` does not use any special fonts -- it's the usual `CM` fonts

Comment: Many document classes, among which are the standard ones, do not select any particular font by themselves: the main document font can be changed independently by loading an appropriate package, _e.g._, `times`.